# Turned Bones in imported model

Tags: bones

first I'm a complete beginner with Blender. I want to position a few models for 3D-printing. For this I have extracted the player figure model and clothes from a game. Combining both was easy done so far by adding "Copy Transforms" as "Bone Constraint" to the clothes and selecting the figure armature as "Target" and the matching figure model bone name as "Bone".

But for some unknown reason the bones inside the right leg of the figure are turned by 180°. Because of this adding for example the right shoe to the figure doesn't work.

This picture shows the bones inside the legs:
[image]

The shoe bones are the the same on both sides because there exists only one shoe model for both legs:

[image]

When I add the shoes with a "Copy Transforms" to both legs it looks like this:

[image]

I have already tried to edit the three bones inside the shoe for the right side by switching direction and position but it still looked like a mess.

Is there a legit reason why the model creators have implemented the bones in such a asymmetric way? How could I handle this in the easiest way?

Edit:
With using a Copy Rotation bone constraint the issue almost seems to be solved.
I have added first a Copy Transforms and then a Copy Rotation constraint with all axis inverted:
[image]
This worked for two of the three bones. For the bone "Ankle_Assist_R" this does not work completely. As the picture shows the Y-inversion works, but invertign X and Z does not change anything. What could be the reason for that?
This picture shows "Ankle_Assist_R" of the leg:
[image]
And this picture shows "Ankle_Assist_R" of the shoe:
[image]

Edit:
Here is another example with a different shoe. In this case the inversion of all axis seems to work but none of them make the shoe turn in the front direction. How could this be achieved?
[image]

Comment: At this point it's hard to tell without having the file. Please upload it on [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/) and share the link here.

Answer (score 0):

There can be many reasons as to why the bones orientation isn't the same on each side. Most of the time, it's to easily allow making symmetrical pauses: same axes will move the same way, while opposite axes will move the opposite way.

It's not as common to see rigs built this way in Blender because we have posing tools for symmetry that do a better job to begin with.

A simple way to do what you want is to either use Copy Location/Rotation/Scale constraints instead of the Copy Transform, or add a Copy Rotation after the Copy Transform (not sure if one is better).

The Copy Rotation constraint have the option to invert the rotation axes:

[image: constraints]

Comment: Thats for your answer. The Copy Rotation seem to be the right fix for this issue, but it only works on two of the three bones and I don't know why. I have extended the post with new pictures to show the issue.